# ImportError: No module named saml2.auth

Tags: python, saml, onelogin

I'm trying to build a SAML authentication mechanism in Python using the OneLogin module, but I keep getting this error: ImportError: No module named saml2.auth

I have followed the steps listed here:

https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml

and installed dependencies as well but i can't install xmlsec library and it says Failed building wheel for xmlsec and failed with error code 1.
(I have done pip install wheel as well)

Any suggestions how to get around this error?

Comment: I'd look in https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/issues and post additional details about your environment

Comment: @xverges Thanks. I realized all i need was the latest version with everything fixed from here: https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases/tag/1.3.5

Comment: @Abullah Nice! Then you should add what you did as an answer (with additional details), or delete the question.

Comment: @xverges i installed xmlsec from the link i mentioned (pip install "path to xmlsec-1.3.52.dev0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64") and then pip install python3-saml and both installed correctly. Then i had a python file which had an import statement "from onelogin.saml2.auth import OneLogin_Saml2_Auth" and i ran this file after the above installs and there was no error. Also if you try to install python3-saml before xmlsec it gives an error.

Comment: Thanks! What I was trying to tell you is that, if you were able to solve your problem, you should create an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer But now I see that you still don't have enough reputation. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xmlsec](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec) (a dependency of python3-saml) had some installation issues on version previous of 1.3.5.

[v1.3.5](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases/tag/1.3.5) solved those issues

Answer (score 3):

Solved by:

`sudo pip install python3-saml`

Answer (score 0):

All i needed was the latest version with everything fixed from here: github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases/tag/1.3.5